# firebaseui-ios FirebaseTableViewDataSource synchronisation with UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebaseui

I'm using FirebaseUI-IOS and the FirebaseTableViewDataSource to bind to my UITableView. For my implementation the UITableView should show Invitations in a 'pending' state to connect users, similar to LinkedIn. The Invitation data stored in Firebase has a Status key that can be either 'pending', 'accepted' or 'rejected'. I am struggling to get the UITableView to update and display only the 'pending' rows after the user has accepted/rejected an invitation. What currently happens is that the UITableView cell gets updated (the name label changes to it's default text), but the cell is still displayed. It seems that the UITableView is bound to all rows under the user's 'received' node, rather than responding to when the status != 'pending'.

My data in Firebase is structured as follows:

[Firebase 'Invitation' data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxIMn.png)

I am using the following code in ViewDidLoad() to initialise the FirebaseTableViewDataSource and populate the cell:

```
    //Initialise a Firebase reference to the authorised user's 'received' invitations data
    self.ref = Firebase(url: "\(kFBInvitationsUsersRef)/\(authData.uid)/received")

    //Query the location for invitations where the status is pending only
    self.ref.queryOrderedByChild("status").queryStartingAtValue(InvitationStatus.pending.rawValue).queryEndingAtValue(InvitationStatus.pending.rawValue).observeEventType(.ChildChanged , withBlock: {(snapshot) in
    } )

    //Assign the tableview datasource to a new FirebaseTableViewDataSource instance using the Firebase ref created above
    self.dataSource = FirebaseTableViewDataSource(query: self.ref, modelClass:nil, prototypeReuseIdentifier: "invitationCell", view: self.tableView)

    //Call the populateCellWithBlock method and configure the cell
    self.dataSource.populateCellWithBlock { (cell: UITableViewCell, obj: NSObject) -> Void in
        let cell = cell as! InvitationTableViewCell
        let snap = obj as! FDataSnapshot

        if let status = snap.value["status"] as? String where status == InvitationStatus.pending.rawValue {
            let userRef = Firebase(url: "\(kFBUsersPublicRef)/\(snap.key)")
            userRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {snapshot in

                let user = User(key: snapshot.key, displayName: snapshot.value["displayName"] as! String, givenName: snapshot.value["givenName"]  as! String, familyName: snapshot.value["familyName"]  as! String)
                cell.user = user
                cell.delegate = self
            })
        }
    }
    self.tableView.dataSource = self.dataSource
    self.tableView.delegate = self
}
```

Can anyone help diagnose what I'm doing wrong here? Is my approach correct?

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: It's not totally clear what you are trying to do. Do you want to query for all pending and populate a tableView based on that query (Firebase handles the filtering)? Or do you want to populate a tableView with pending, where the results are filtered in code? Do you want to watch for ongoing changes? If you haven't done so, take a look at [Build Better Mobile Apps](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-08-27-firebaseui-makes-mobile-easy.html). Take note of the iOS quick start code and build upon that. If you simplify your code, the answer may present itself.

Comment: @Jay, thank you for your input, sorry if the requirement isn't clear. I am trying to get the tableView to display all rows with a status of pending. When the user updates the status by tapping the accept or reject button in the cell, the row disappears from the tableView. I would like to achieve this by observing changes to the status key. The existing code is based on the structure described in the link you provided.

Comment: Questions: Why is there queryOrderedByChild with an empty block? - that block is what is called when the query returns. Also, queryEqualToValue("pending") may be more clear, if that's what you were looking for.. If the intention is to query for pending, then why also check for 'pending' in code? Is this statement correct: When the user taps accepted or rejected, that change is written out to Firebase, which in turn, reloads the tableView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed my approach to this to find a solution. I've modified my data structure in Firebase so that the statuses become keys. I then bind the FirebaseTableViewDataSource to the reference for the 'pending' key. When the user accepts/rejects the invitation it gets deleted from the 'pending' node and created on the 'accepted'/'rejected' node. The tableView now updates as expected when new 'pending' invitations are added or existing 'pending' invitations are accepted/rejected.